# Concatenate rows of a column based on values of another column

Tags: r, concatenation, paste

I have this format of data:

```
       df <- data.frame(seqpart=factor(c("", "ccagttgttg", "tttgattcg", "ctttgtc","", "ctttgtcga","cttagta", "ttactgt", "ttacat")), 
       seqinfo= factor(c("IDseq1|specie1", "", "","","IDseq2|specie2","","","","")))

 > df
   seqpart         seqinfo
   <NA>            IDseq1|specie1
   ccagttgttg      <NA>
   tttgattcg       <NA>
   ctttgtc         <NA>
   <NA>            IDseq2|specie2
   ctttgtcga       <NA>
   cttagta         <NA>
   ttactgt         <NA>
   ttacat          <NA>
```

I would like to concatenate rows depending on the column `seqinfo` to construct another data with this new format:

```
>df1    
 seqinfo             seq
 IDseq1|specie1      ccagttgttgtttgattcgctttgtc
 IDseq2|specie2      ctttgtcgacttagtattactgtttacat
```

Is there a way to do this? Many thanks

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far that doesn't appear to work.

Comment: The definition of `df` with `""` for empty entries doesn't match to the output of `print(df)` where empty entries are denoted by `<NA>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create a grouping variable ('grp') based on the presence of non-blank elements in 'seqinfo', get the non-blank element from 'seqinfo' and `paste` the 'seqpart' together

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(seqinfo = seqinfo[seqinfo!=''], 
  seqpart = paste(seqpart, collapse='')),.(grp = cumsum(seqinfo !=""))][, grp := NULL][]
#          seqinfo                       seqpart
#1: IDseq1|specie1    ccagttgttgtttgattcgctttgtc
#2: IDseq2|specie2 ctttgtcgacttagtattactgtttacat
```

Answer (score 3):

Another idea via `tidyverse`. We first replace `''` with NA and fill them. We group by `seqinfo` and paste the unique `seqparts`, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 mutate_all(funs(replace(., . == '', NA))) %>% 
 fill(seqpart, .direction = 'up') %>% 
 fill(seqinfo) %>% 
 group_by(seqinfo) %>% 
 summarise(seqpart = paste(unique(seqpart), collapse = ''))
```

> ```
>   A tibble: 2 x 2
>          seqinfo                       seqpart
>           <fctr>                         <chr>
> 1 IDseq1|specie1    ccagttgttgtttgattcgctttgtc
> 2 IDseq2|specie2 ctttgtcgacttagtattactgtttacat
> ```

Answer (score 1):

There is also an alternative `data.table` solution which uses `na.locf()` (Last Observation Carried Forward):

```
library(data.table)
data.table(df)[, seqinfo := zoo::na.locf(droplevels(seqinfo, ""))][
  , .(seq = paste(seqpart, collapse = "")), by = seqinfo]
```

> ```
>           seqinfo                           seq
> 1: IDseq1|specie1    ccagttgttgtttgattcgctttgtc
> 2: IDseq2|specie2 ctttgtcgacttagtattactgtttacat
> ```

#### Data

```
df <- data.frame(
  seqpart=factor(c("", "ccagttgttg", "tttgattcg", "ctttgtc", "", "ctttgtcga",
                   "cttagta", "ttactgt", "ttacat")), 
  seqinfo= factor(c("IDseq1|specie1", "", "", "", "IDseq2|specie2", "", "", "", "")))
```

#### Variant in case of `NA`

The call to `droplevels()` can be skipped if the empty entries are coded as `NA` instead of `""`:

```
df1 <- fread(
"   seqpart         seqinfo
   <NA>            IDseq1|specie1
  ccagttgttg      <NA>
  tttgattcg       <NA>
  ctttgtc         <NA>
  <NA>            IDseq2|specie2
  ctttgtcga       <NA>
  cttagta         <NA>
  ttactgt         <NA>
  ttacat          <NA>",
  na.strings = "<NA>"
)

data.table(df1)[, seqinfo := zoo::na.locf(seqinfo)][
  , .(seq = paste(seqpart, collapse = "")), by = seqinfo]
```